# How to stop Logged in user credentials prepopulated in similar controls in other view like username & password

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I'm developing MVC 4 web application with razor engine. in which i have created FormsAuthenticationTicket to username and password. Which is working fine.

First time when i login to application browser requests to remember username and password on the same browser. If I say YES it is populating username and password in login page when i run application.

After login to an application, I have a registration page where i have similar fields like username password (what i have in login page) to create / invite new user to application they are pre populating with  the log in user credentials automatically. they suppose to be blank in this registration page.

for this i have gone through various help sites and recommended to keep autocomplete="off" which is not working in Chrome and Fireforx(mozilla) browsers only works in IE.

I have also placed this property in form leavel and field (control) leavel but of no use.

Comment: Clear your ModelState.

Answer (score 0):

use autocomplete

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { autocomplete = "off" })
```

Comment: this works great in those browsers for us.  If you look at the rendered text box do you see autocomplete="off" in the tag?

Answer (score 0):

You should use `@Html.PasswordFor(model => model.Password)` for security reason and to prevent accidental resubmits.

`@Html.TextBoxFor(x => x.UserName, new { autocomplete = "off" })` does not always work in all browsers